# SFML SetFramerateLimit Not Limiting Frame Rate

Tags: c++, sfml

Compiler: Visual C++
OS: Windows 7 Enterprise

For some reason, `Window::SetFramerateLimit` isn't limiting the frame rate in the app I'm working on, but it works fine for others. The framerate is capped to 60, but mine jumps around at 100-99 and then goes down to 50 sometimes. It actually causes serious issues. For example, if I create many objects on screen, I'll see a heavy performance hit, whereas others report no change.

Any ideas regarding why this is happening? If you need more information, I'd be happy to oblige.

Thanks.

P.S. I have strong reasons to believe that it is not simply a case of "their hardware is just more powerful than yours."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved by setting vertical sync to true.